# Error Deploying War File on jboss 7.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, war, java-7

I am trying to deploy a war file on RHEL5 server using jboss 7.1 and it is failing once I put it in the deployment folder, I checked the server.log and found that it is getting this error when trying to deploy:

> [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-8) Failed to define class
>   tag.TagBean in Module "deployment.AppWeb.war:main" from Service Module
>   Loader: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: tag/TagBean :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Where tag is a namespace in the Web project AppWeb and TagBean is the class name.
One more thing, in the struts file it is added like this:

```
<package name="tag" namespace="/tag" extends="struts-default">
         <action name="default" class="tag.TagBean">
             <result>myForm.submitpage.jsp</result>
         </action>
    </package>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to run application (at least class `tag.TagBean`) compiled with Java 7 on older JVM.
Either [switch JVM to Java 7](https://community.jboss.org/message/742171) or recompile with Java 6.

Comment: I already done that and it work, but since it is the right answer I will set it as the right answer thank you

Comment: now i am getting this error, can you help: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.Object

Comment: Post another question, please.